# Por qué no se envía la info desde el formulario html al PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios

Estoy montando un formulario en una página web y resulta que los emails llegan sin la información captada del formulario. Solo me llegan las etiquetas que agregué dentro de la variable **$contenido**, y no los datos recibidos en la web. Le agregué el IF al php para que no enviara el correo si no recibía los datos, y no me están llegando correos.El **var_dump($_POST)** me arroja **NULL**

```js
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

  if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['subject']) AND !empty($_POST['message'])){
    
  $destino="contacto@mail.com";
  $nombre=$_POST["name"];
  $correo=$_POST["email"];
  $asunto=$_POST["subject"];
  $mensaje=$_POST["message"];
  $headers = "From: mi@cuentadeemail.com" . "\r\n" .
  $contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre."\nCorreo: ".$correo."\nAsunto: ".$asunto."\nMensaje: ".$mensaje;
             
  mail($destino, $asunto, $contenido, $headers);
  header("Location: index.html");

}

?>
```

```html
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="post.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Asunto" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

array(0) { } array(5) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(0) { } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> array(5) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(0) { } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> *RECURSION* } }

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120397/discussion-on-question-by-camilogrifi-por-que-no-se-envia-la-info-desde-el-formu).

Answer (score -1):

Verifica que tu ruta (action="post.php") sea correcta, para esto podrias inspeccionar el código desde el navegador y ver si esta bien escrita

Comment: Esta en el mismo directorio del **index.html**, y si puedo verificar y ver lo que arroja el **var_dump** en la ruta del `posp.php`

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]